# "join expression not supported" in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am writing a SQL query with inner join as this

```
select * from (table1 inner join table2 on table1.city = table2.code)
   inner join table3 on table3.col1 = 5 and table3.col2 = 'Hello'
```

This giving me the error "Join expression not supported".

However, if I change the query like this then there is no error

```
select * from (table1 inner join table2 on table1.city = table2.code)
   inner join table3 on table3.col1 = [SomeColumn] and table3.col2 = [SomeColumn]
```

Why is Access giving me an error on the first query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is Access giving me an error on the first query?

Well, like the error message says, that form of a JOIN expression is not supported.

You might want to try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3 
WHERE table1.city=table2.code AND table3.col1=5 AND table3.col2='Hello'
```

Comment: Well this is an alternate solution, instead of using join that will not help if there are more table, but work on this situation, thanks

Answer (score 37):

Very late but I had a similar problem with JOIN expressions on MS Access, like described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/join-expression-not-supported-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising-string?forum=accessdev) Access sometimes needs everything inside the ON part of the query to be inside parenthesis, ie:

`SELECT ... JOIN <table> ON (everything here inside the parenthesis) WHERE ...`

Comment: This!! Thank you.

Comment: This is the actual answer.

Comment: Late to the party, but this should be the accepted solution.

Comment: And if this still doesn't work? Keeps telling me it's still not supported.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers work for INNER JOIN, they did not work for LEFT JOIN for me.

```
-- error: join expression not supported
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table1.id = table2.t1id AND table1.fld = 'Hello')
```

The solution was to remove the 'Hello' condition out of the LEFT JOIN. The trick is to add " `OR table1.fld IS NULL` " to still have all results from table1.

```
-- working as expected
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table1 ON (table1.id = table2.t1id)
WHERE table1.fld = 'Hello' OR table1.fld IS NULL
```