# MS-ACCESS Using LEFT JOIN with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, left-join, ms-access-2013

```
SELECT
U.[Current Month], 
U.[Security Name],
U.[CM Return],
(P1.[Return] * P2.[Return] * P3.[Return] * P4.[Return] * P5.[Return] * P6.[Return] * P7.[Return]) AS [7 Month Return],
(P1.[Return] * P2.[Return] * P3.[Return] * P4.[Return] * P5.[Return] * P6.[Return] * P7.[Return] * P8.[Return]) AS [8 Month Return],
(P1.[Return] * P2.[Return] * P3.[Return] * P4.[Return] * P5.[Return] * P6.[Return] * P7.[Return] * P8.[Return] * P9.[Return]) AS [9 Month Return],
(P1.[Return] * P2.[Return] * P3.[Return] * P4.[Return] * P5.[Return] * P6.[Return] * P7.[Return] * P8.[Return] * P9.[Return] * P10.[Return]) AS [10 Month Return],
(P1.[Return] * P2.[Return] * P3.[Return] * P4.[Return] * P5.[Return] * P6.[Return] * P7.[Return] * P8.[Return] * P9.[Return] * P10.[Return] * P11.[Return]) AS [11 Month Return]
FROM ((((((((((((
[Prior Month Returns Tbl] AS U
INNER JOIN [Securities] AS S ON U.[Security Name] = S.[Security Name])
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P1 ON P1.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P1.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-1,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P2 ON P2.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P2.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-2,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P3 ON P3.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P3.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-3,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P4 ON P4.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P4.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-4,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P5 ON P5.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P5.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-5,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P6 ON P6.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P6.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-6,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P7 ON P7.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P7.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-7,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P8 ON P8.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P8.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-8,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P9 ON P9.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P9.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-9,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P10 ON P10.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P10.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-10,U.[Current Month]))
LEFT JOIN [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P11 ON P11.[Security ID] = S.[ID] AND P11.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-11,U.[Current Month]))
WHERE S.ID = 14
```

Above is the MS-ACCESS Query that i want to execute. What i want to do is simple for the security id 14 i want to count the multiplication of the previous 7 to  11 months returns from the [Data 9 to 17 Monthly] table for the current month in [Prior Month Returns Tbl]. the query works fine if i use inner join but it will omit the result if not all the previous 11 months records are present in the [Data 9 to 17 Monthly] so thats why i am using left join but i am getting error that JOIN EXPRESSION NOT SUPPORTED. Please Help. I know this query would work fine in t-sql. What should i do that this query also work in MS-Access?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080760616.aspx or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608313/join-expression-not-supported-in-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an outer join, MS Access does not support conditions that are not between the two tables.  This is a very strange limitation in my opinion.

You can work around it with subqueries.  Here is an example:

```
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT P1.*
 FROM [Data 9 17 Monthly] AS P1
 WHERE P1.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m",-1,U.[Current Month]))
) as P1
ON P1.[Security ID] = S.[ID]
```

Alternatively, you could combine all the data into a single row using conditional aggregation:

```
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT [Security ID],
        MAX(IIF(P1.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m", -1, U.[Current Month])), [RETURN], 1) as Return_01,
        MAX(IIF(P1.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m", -2, U.[Current Month])), [RETURN], 1) as Return_02,
        . . .
        MAX(IIF(P1.[Date Month] = DateAdd("m", -12, U.[Current Month])), [RETURN], 1) as Return_12
) as P
ON P.[Security ID] = S.[ID]
```

And then adjust the outer `SELECT` as needed.

Or, you could upgrade to a more ANSI-compliant database.

Comment: The first solution looks good. worked for me it resolved the JOIN EXPRESSION NOT SUPPORTED error but access asked me for the value of U.[Current Month]. why did it ask me for value it should be taken from the inner join i did before right? for now i have worked around this issue by creating separate queries for each Previous month multiplication.

Comment: @KrunalParekh . . . I messed up on that part of the answer.  I didn't notice that `[Current Month]` comes from a different table.  That complicates matters a bit.  I wonder if your original query would work with `and on` rather than `and` (yet another MS Access weirdism).

Comment: It took me hours to come across the solution. (Damned MS A!)