# SQL Left Join multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, relational-database

I have 5 relational tables, let's say a,b,c,d,e.

How can I left join 4 of the tables "b,c,d,e" onto table "a" using a unique column "ID" which is present in all the tables?

I want to do this in MS Access using sql query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access Left Join not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185315/ms-access-left-join-not-working-correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access, you need a bunch of parentheses:

```
select . . .
from (((a left join
        b
        on a.id = b.id
       ) left join
       c
       on a.id = c.id
      ) left join
      d
      on a.id = d.id
     )
     on a.id = e.id;
```