# MS Acces Jet SQL Error: Join Expression not supported with multiple Join conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet, jet-sql

I'm trying to run this SQL Expression in Access:

```
Select *
From ((TableA
    Left Join TableB
        On TableB.FK = TableA.PK)
    Left Join TableC
        On TableC.FK = TableB.PK)
    Left Join (SELECT a,b,c FROM TableD WHERE b > 1) AS TableD
        On (TableD.FK = TableC.PK AND TableA.a = TableD.a)
```

but it keeps getting error: Join-Expression not supported.
Whats the problem?
Sorry, im just starting with Jet-SQL and in T-SQL its all fine. 
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["join expression not supported" in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608313/join-expression-not-supported-in-access)

Comment: Not the cause of your issue, but `TableD.FK` won't exist in the context of your query.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the final outer join condition `TableA.a = TableD.a` will cause the query to contain [ambiguous outer joins](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/video-fix-the-ambiguous-outer-join-error-c36948dc-c481-48c6-809d-38427e9ffdd7), since the records to which `TableA` is joined to `TableD` will depend upon the results of the joins between `TableA->TableB`, `TableB->TableC` and `TableC->TableD`.

To avoid this, you'll likely need to structure your query with the joins between tables `TableA`, `TableB` & `TableC` existing within a subquery, the result of which is then outer joined to `TableD`. This unambiguously defines the order in which the joins are evaluated.

For example:

```
select * from
(
    select TableA.a, TableC.PK from
    (
        TableA left join TableB on TableA.PK = TableB.FK
    )
    left join TableC on TableB.PK = TableC.FK
) q1
left join
(
    select TableD.a, TableD.b, TableD.c, TableD.FK from TableD 
    where TableD.b > 1
) q2 
on q1.a = q2.a and q1.PK = q2.FK
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider relating every join to the `FROM` table to avoid having to nest relations.

```
SELECT *
FROM ((TableA
    LEFT JOIN TableB
        ON TableB.FK = TableA.PK)
    LEFT JOIN TableC
        ON TableC.FK = TableA.PK)
    LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT FK,a,b,c
           FROM TableD WHERE b > 1
          ) AS TableD
        ON  (TableD.FK = TableA.PK)
        AND (TableD.a  = TableA.a)
```