# "Join expression not supported" for more than two ON conditions with an INNER JOIN

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have been struggling with various syntax errors on a query in MS Access that works fine in TSQL.

For example, I learned that MS Access requires parentheses when there are more than one left/inner joins, and also if there is more than one ON condition for any of those joins, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23632282/5042393) and [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468/quotjoin-expression-not-supportedquot-error-caused-by-unbracketed-join-expression-comprising?forum=accessdev).

However, I am now stuck with another "Join expression not supported" error, when I have three ON conditions for an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT *  
FROM ((
        (Table1
        INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Col2 = Table1.Col2)

        LEFT JOIN Table3 
        ON (Table1.id = Table3.fid
             and Table3.Col2 > SomeNumber)
        )

        LEFT JOIN Table4 
        ON (Table4.Col2 = Table3.Col2
             and Table4.Col4 = 'SomeValue'
             and Table4.fid = Table1.x_id)
        )
```

The above gets the "Join expression not supported" error, but if I remove any one of the three conditions in the last LEFT JOIN ON, the SQL was fine, like this:

```
SELECT *  
FROM ((
    (Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Col2 = Table1.Col2)

    LEFT JOIN Table3 
    ON (Table1.id = Table3.fid
         and Table3.Col2 > SomeNumber)
    )

    LEFT JOIN Table4 
    ON (Table4.Col2 = Table3.Col2
         and Table4.fid = Table1.x_id)
    )
```

Any two of the three conditions was accepted in the above. I have even tried adding additional parentheses like this but it didn't work either:

```
    LEFT JOIN Table4 
        ON ((Table4.Col2 = Table3.Col2
             and Table4.Col4 = 'SomeValue')
             and Table4.fid = Table1.x_id)
        )
```

Please help - thanks!

Comment: Are you using Access query design view to build query?

Comment: Hi @June7, I am using the query SQL view.

Comment: So why don't you build with Design View then switch to SQLView to see result?